# ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2] stops RubyMine from auto-completing

Tags: rubymine

I used RubyMine CTRL+ALT+G to generate a Model called User

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I try to use autocomplete and it doesnt work. 
I remove `[5.2]`. It works.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I am using Rails 5.2 and Ruby 2.5.1p57 inside of a RVM installation on RubyMine 2018.2

I have tried invalidating caches.

How do I get autocomplete to work?